# date comparison does not work with aggregation

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I have recently upgraded my database from Oracle 10.2g to Oracle 11.2.0.4.0g. when I run query to find count it gives zero records but when I with asterisk * it gives detail of records perfectly. following is my query. CPRODUCT is a view.

```
SELECT
COUNT(*)
FROM
"CPRODUCT"
INNER JOIN "CATEGORY" ON CATEGORY.ID = CPRODUCT.PID
WHERE
( lastdate BETWEEN '27-OCT-21' AND '27-OCT-21')
and ( "ACGCODE" ='01150');
```

I can not understand what is happening. Please help me anyone.

Comment: That's hard to believe. Please, post sample data which illustrate what you are saying. Also, don't compare dates to strings and use table aliases with column names.

Comment: @WaseemHassan What is the datatype of your lastdate column?

Comment: `COUNT()` is not a function. The query probably didn't run at all.

Comment: @Boneist the datatype of lastdate is DATE.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. the view "CPRODUCT" as having

```
ORDER BY TO_DATE("CPRODUCT"."LASTDATE")
```

which is removed and it worked after that.